# sudo pecl install apc returns error

Tags: php, pear, apc, pecl

I run the command: `sudo pecl install apc`

The file gets downloaded, the configuration succeeds, then `make` is launched and I get the following error.

`/usr/include/php5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory`

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

PCRE is a dependency for installing APC.  You can install it pretty quick with

`yum install pcre-devel` or `apt-get install libpcre3-dev`

once it's installed, re-run

`sudo pecl install apc`

Comment: PCRE is required but [the docs](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/apc.requirements.php) still say: 
"No external libraries are needed to build this extension."

Comment: `sudo apt-get install build-essential` may help with the external libraries issue.

Answer (score 12):

sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev is the answer.

So to be able to install pecl [install extension]

the following packages are required:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pear php5-dev libpcre3-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

What version of PHP?

For a while, some months ago, I had trouble installing APC, and could only make it work with `pecl install apc-beta`

If you're not dealing with a production system, you might try that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you install a PHP extension via PECL before?

Does the file `/usr/include/php5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h` actually exist?

You could get this error because of the following

1. Incorrect permissions
2. PECL directory configuration is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the development version of PHP5. On Ubuntu you can install it using:

```
sudo aptitude install php5-dev
```

Comment: I received this error after installing php5-dev, unfortunately (Ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 0):

I have posted an answer for the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555561/error-building-fatal-error-pcre-h-no-such-file-or-directory/22559967#22559967). But I am still posting here for reference

To include pcre.h file, search the package archives for the pcre.h file.
To do this I use a command called apt-file (

> apt-get install apt-file

and

> apt-file update

if you don’t have it installed).
Then search for the pcre package:

> apt-file search -x "/pcre.h$"

The -x informs the command that I want to use a regular expression as the pattern. apt-file provided me with three hits:

- kannel-dev: /usr/include/kannel/gwlib/pcre.h
- libajax6-dev: /usr/include/ajax/pcre.h
- libpcre3-dev: /usr/include/pcre.h

The last one is the one I want:

> apt-get install libpcre3-dev

This will solve the problem with pcre.h file compilation problem. Hope it will help others, who may come to find an answer to this thread.