# Intalling PECL APC on ubuntu and dreamhost hosting

Tags: php, jquery, ubuntu-10.04, apc

Basically My aim is to use the following script on my website

[php-upload-progress-bar](http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/)

I want to first of all set it up on my local server which is on ubuntu 10.04 and i am using xampp1.7.7 and then upload it on my website which is hosted by dreamhost web hosting which uses php5.2

The main requirement of above script is to have [APC](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC) .

My problem is that i am unable to set up APC on both server (my local and on dreamhost)

I have followed many tutorials to install it but coudn't install it

Can someone give me some idea about using APC and installing it to run above script??

I have already followed following tutorials and guides

[Dreamhost wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Pecl_APC)

[Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720666/sudo-pecl-install-apc-returns-error)

PS;I am not using apache2 service.my php path is /opt/lampp/htocs

Please help me i am stuck in this and also i am using that upload script because i can not use flash,html5 or php5.3 acording to client requirement so i need a solution for upload progress bar using APC so that it will run in all browser and with php5.2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to contact DreamHost support for more immediate assistance.  As for the APC extension, it is not enabled on our php 5.2 or php 5.3 options, as you mentioned.  The easiest way to do this will likely be to compile the apc module for php 5.3 and then setup the custom phprc file for it under your user.  This wiki details the process:

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PHP.ini#Compiling_PHP_5.3_extensions

-- I tested doing a install right now, the steps were:

Download the APC package from PECL:  http://pecl.php.net/package/APC

extract it, enter the directory, run phpize, then run:

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php53/bin/php-config
then make
mkdir -p ~/.php/5.3
cp modules/apc.so ~/.php/5.3
then edit the file ~/.php/5.3 and put into it:
extension=/home/USER/.php/5.3/apc.so
```

(replacing USER with your real ssh username)

save it, and you should be good to go.

Feel free to write us at support if you have any additional questions.