# PHP stopped working on apache

Tags: php, apache

I was following a [tutorial](http://www.alihan.com.tr/blog/installing-apc-opcode-cache-on-centos-5-64-bit.html) to install APC on my centos vps, and then I ran into a trouble, so found some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720666/sudo-pecl-install-apc-returns-error), now my PHP isn't working on apache.

Only the very root index.php works, no other root pages, none in sub directories. If I access the php directly, it forces a download of the file.

This is odd because php has always worked on the server for over a year. When I check error_log, I see this.

```
[Thu Feb 27 05:56:35 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Feb 27 05:56:35 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Feb 27 05:56:35 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Feb 27 05:56:35 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Feb 27 05:56:35 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Seems like the issue is related with the PHP handler.... May I know what is the current PHP handler you have in your server ? Also is there any control panels like cpanel there ?

Comment: However the steps provided [here](http://www.alihan.com.tr/blog/installing-apc-opcode-cache-on-centos-5-64-bit.html) is not that complicated to mess the php handler.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a completely normal log

```
[Thu Feb 27 05:56:35 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

SIGTERM is sent to daemons being shutdown/restarted

```
[Thu Feb 27 05:56:35 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

The server is starting, suExec is enabled

```
[Thu Feb 27 05:56:35 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Feb 27 05:56:35 2014] [notice] Digest: done
```

Digest authentication is initialized

```
[Thu Feb 27 05:56:35 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Apache is ready.

You should use the most paranoid logging settings you can for PHP, it hasn't yet told you what is wrong ;)