# Error building : fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory

Tags: php, ubuntu, build, phalcon, ubuntu-13.10

I'm just finished installing Ubuntu 13.10.

I want try Phalcon, and when I build the source (phalcon.so), I have this error :

```
     from /home/fabrice/Downloads/cphalcon/build/32bits/phalcon.c:204:
/usr/include/php5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
 #include "pcre.h"
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [phalcon.lo] Erreur 1
```

My installation of lamp is :

> sudo apt-get install -y apache2 php5 mysql-server libapache2-mod-php5
>   php5-mysql  php5-curl php5-imagick  php5-mcrypt php5-memcache 
>   php5-sqlite php5-xdebug php-apc php5-intl  php-mongo php5-dev gcc

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: php -v : PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/phalcon.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/phalcon.so: undefined symbol: php_end_ob_buffer in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.2 (cli) (built: Feb 28 2014 20:03:35) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

Answer (score 237, accepted):

The latest version of Phalcon uses PCRE libraries.

You can install them like so:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
```

and then try and install Phalcon again

For CentOS you will need to use

```
sudo yum install pcre-devel
```

Credits: @[xgretsch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217953/xgretsch)

For Mac you can use

```
brew install pcre
```

Credits @[Brandon Romano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1575117/brandon-romano)

For Mac without `brew`

Go to https://www.pcre.org/ and download latest pcre:,

```
tar -xzvf pcre-8.42.tar.gz
cd pcre-8.42
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pcre-8.42
make
make install
ln -s /usr/local/pcre-8.42 /usr/sbin/pcre
ln -s /usr/local/pcre-8.42/include/pcre.h /usr/include/pcre.h
```

Credits @[user1377324](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377324/user1377324)

Comment: On mac you can use: `brew install pcre`

Comment: Thanks that seems to have fixed the problem for me when installing mongodb's PHP extension using PECL.

Answer (score 10):

For MacOS monterey amd64 (darwin), it is necessary to create a symlink.

First, locate where the `pcre.h` was installed by Brew:

```sh
$ brew list pcre | grep 'pcre\.h$'

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include/pcre.h
```

Then, gets the directory that GCC is looking for header (.h) files:

```sh
$ cpp -v

...
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include   # <---- we are going to use this one
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

Finally, create a symlink to the `pcre.h` file, so that GCC will find it in  its search path:

```sh
ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre/8.45/include/pcre.h \
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/pcre.h
```

To test if it worked, we can use the following C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcre.h>
int main() {
   printf("lala popo");
   return 0;
}
```

And run:

```sh
gcc test.c -o test
```

Answer (score 9):

For mac osx maverick you can use

```
brew install pcre
```

if it gives you error, you can use

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/pcre.h /usr/include/
sudo pecl install apc
```

I have installed pcre via homebrew in Big Sur, so linked as:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/include/pcre2.h /usr/local/include/
```

Comment: also, make sure /usr/local/include/ folder is exists. (mac osx big sur)

Comment: `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/include/pcre.h /usr/local/include/` after `brew install pcre` solved issue with building Haskell project with `stack`

Answer (score 8):

To include pcre.h file, search the package archives for the pcre.h file.
To do this I use a command called apt-file (

> apt-get install apt-file

and

> apt-file update

if you don’t have it installed).

Then search for the pcre package:

> apt-file search -x "/pcre.h$"

The -x informs the command that I want to use a regular expression as the pattern. apt-file provided me with three hits:

- kannel-dev: /usr/include/kannel/gwlib/pcre.h
- libajax6-dev: /usr/include/ajax/pcre.h
- libpcre3-dev: /usr/include/pcre.h

The last one is the one I want:

> apt-get install libpcre3-dev

This will solve the problem with pcre.h file compilation problem. Hope it will help others, who may come to find an answer to this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Using macOS Monterey 12.6 on an M1 Pro MacBook Pro, here are the steps necessary to install `outh` extension for PHP 8.1 using brew:

1. `brew install pcre`
2. `brew install pcre2`
3. `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/include/pcre.h /usr/local/include/`
4. `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/include/pcre2.h /usr/local/include/`
5. `sudo pecl install oauth`