# PHP Phalcon installation error

Tags: php, pcre, phalcon

I was trying to install phalcon in my MAC system but getting this error , Please tell me how can I solve it?

I have run these command

```
 git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
 cd cphalcon/build
 sudo ./install
```

and it show me error:

```
creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
/bin/sh /Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits/libtool --mode=compile gcc  -I. -I/Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits/include -I/Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits/main -I/Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DPHALCON_RELEASE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -O2 -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -fvisibility=hidden   -c /Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c -o phalcon.lo 
mkdir .libs
 gcc -I. -I/Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits/include -I/Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits/main -I/Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DPHALCON_RELEASE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -O2 -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -fvisibility=hidden -c /Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/phalcon.o
In file included from /usr/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27,
                 from /Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:204:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27,
                 from /Users/dladdha/test/cphalcon/build/64bits/phalcon.c:204:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:37: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:38: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘pcre’
make: *** [phalcon.lo] Error 1
```

Anyone has solution for it ??

Comment: Have a look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555561/error-building-fatal-error-pcre-h-no-such-file-or-directory/22559967

Answer (score 4):

Have you installed PCRE? http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/pcre/ gives an excellent article on how to do that.

Then in your /usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h file, edit the line that includes pcre.h to include /path/to/pcre.h in your pcre folder.

That worked for me. Good luck!