# Where is file pcre.h in library package pcre-8.37

Tags: c++, c, regex, unix, pcre

I am lost.
I have the Linux CentOS operating system.
I am trying to find the pcre.h in the downloaded pcre package at the pcre website. 
I have also configured it as it is told in the install guide,
but no luck. Any help?

Comment: I dunno, but did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22555561/2173917)?

Comment: it works with yum install pcre-devel!. but why i must to involve yum downloader. can i direct install file pcre.h?

Comment: @zukermanyoav the pcre package contains the files required at runtime . pcre-devel contains the files required for developing. You should use the pcre-devel package since that matches the pcre package you have and as there's more things you need than a single pcre.h header file.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version called PCRE2 and the header file name is pcre2.h here is the path
ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre2-10.00.tar.bz2

In the version you mentioned (8.37) pcre.h will be generated after installation. Try this:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/$USER/pcre/
make
make install
```

pcre package will be installed in your home directory and there you can find pcre.h header.

Comment: ok. so the big question is what the difference between pcre-8.x and pcre2 ? also I need to use only C version not C++.

Comment: isn't the C mantra different from scriptable programming language? why we must go over installation process for each package? the idea must be only one compilation process at C run-time compilation, and not the multiple run-time for each package.

Comment: @zukermanyoav the difference is that PCRE2 has a brand new API, which aims to be easily extensible in the future.