# nginx compiling from source

Tags: nginx, pcre

We needed to include sticky directive in nginx; so we followed steps from this link http://nginx.org/en/docs/howto_build_on_win32.html..
But we are getting below error:

```
 In file included from src/core/ngx_core.h:71:0,
        from src/core/nginx.c:9:
 src/core/ngx_regex.h:15:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
```

This link had similar issue 
[Error building : fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555561/error-building-fatal-error-pcre-h-no-such-file-or-directory)
but i am using latest of pcre i.e. pcre2-10.10

Can anybody tell how to correct the issue or any location from which i can download nginx with sticky module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't use pcre2. You need pcre like pcre-8.36.