# Install phalcon on macOS Mojave

Tags: pcre, phalcon, macos-mojave

I've just upgraded to Mojave and am trying to install phalcon, it was smooth installation with standard compile installation on macOS previous version (High Sierra),

```
git clone git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install
```

with Mojave, it gives follow error.

```
In file included from /usr/include/php/ext/spl/spl_iterators.h:27:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:10: fatal error: 'pcre.h' file not found
#include "pcre.h"
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [phalcon.lo] Error 1
```

anyone encounter the same problem? it would be good to know how to get it solved.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555561/error-building-fatal-error-pcre-h-no-such-file-or-directory/22559967#22559967

Comment: @NikolaosDimopoulos thanks, I did look at that thread. But I am not intend to install with brew.

Answer (score 0):

OK after a few trying, this is what I do to fix it, hope it would help for someone else.
Go to https://www.pcre.org/ and download latest pcre, more specifically,

```
tar -xzvf pcre-8.42.tar.gz
cd pcre-8.42
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pcre-8.42
make
make install
ln -s /usr/local/pcre-8.42 /usr/sbin/pcre
ln -s /usr/local/pcre-8.42/include/pcre.h /usr/include/pcre.h
```

and it went through.

Comment: `ln -s /usr/local/pcre-8.42 /usr/sbin/pcre

ln -s /usr/local/pcre-8.42/include/pcre.h /usr/include/pcre.h`
these operations are not permitted. What should I do? @user1377324

Answer (score 0):

I have Mojave on my Mac, and i installed Phalcon into my Mac through HomeBrew, step by step

1/Install php through brew (with correct version)
2/Install phalcon through brew

Hope it can help you